# How can i import from binary to float in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Im working on SSIS 2008.

I have an issue when i tried to import a flat file that is on binary. I had no problems with the normal records but when i tried to read a float number, it didn't recognized. I tried differents ways and also saw for a Unpack Decimal component, nothing works. In the last attempt i get the number in hexadecimal notation but dont know how to convert it into a float number.

I get something like this when i see the record on SQL:
Column 1        Column 2        Column 3
Cx0000000000500013  Cx0000000000000310  Cx0000000000000056

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure you can import from binary - what binary encoding are you dealing with? How was the file created?

Comment: EBCDIC 37 i guess, i used it to read other registers, i'm not familiar with binary files. It was created by SAS, not sure how, im not into its creation.